# Inserir dados com LIST em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando inserir registro de treinamento em uma lista que está sendo usada no lugar de uma base de dados, mas em alguma parte da aplicação ela se perde e a lista mantém apenas o registro que foi inserido via código no construtor da classe TrainingRepository. A princípio achei que fosse por causa do controller que está sempre sendo chamado e por isso estaria limpado a minha lista.

**Repository**

```
public class TrainingRepository : ITrainingRepository
{
    private List<Treinamento> allTrainings;
    private List<Treinamento> trainingData = new List<Treinamento>(); // Repositório
    public TrainingRepository()
    {
        allTrainings = new List<Treinamento>();

        trainingData.Add(new Treinamento() { ID = 1, Name = "João da Silva", Duration = "45min", StartDate = DateTime.Parse("10/10/2015"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("31/10/2015"), Instructor = "Paula", Time = "4:00PM" });

        allTrainings.AddRange(trainingData.ToList<Treinamento>());
    }

    public IEnumerable<Treinamento> GetTrainings()
    {
        return allTrainings;
    }

    public Treinamento GetTrainingByID(int id)
    {
        return allTrainings.Find(t => t.ID == id);
    }

    public void InsertTraining(Treinamento training)
    {
        training.ID = (from b in trainingData orderby b.ID descending select b.ID).FirstOrDefault() + 1;

        trainingData.Add(new Treinamento()
        {
            ID = training.ID,
            Name = training.Name,
            Instructor = training.Instructor,
            StartDate = training.StartDate,
            EndDate = training.EndDate,
            Time = training.Time,
            Duration = training.Duration
        });
    }

    public List<string> GetInstructor()
    {
        var mainItems = (from key in trainingData select key.Instructor).Distinct().ToList();
        return mainItems.ToList();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    TrainingRepository _trainingRepository = new TrainingRepository();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Treinamento> allTrainings = _trainingRepository.GetTrainings().ToList();
        return View(allTrainings);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreatePartialView()
    {
        return PartialView("CreatePartialView");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Create(Treinamento training)
    {
        _trainingRepository.InsertTraining(training);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetInstructorList()
    {
        var allInstructors = _trainingRepository.GetInstructor().ToList();
        return Json(allInstructors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sendo que você realiza uma requisição à Controller, uma nova instancia da mesma é instanciada e com isto você está criando um novo repositório junto.

Como é interessante manter uma UnitOfWork para cada instancia da Controller, é realmente interessante que o repositório seja instanciando a cada requisição.

por um outro lado, o seu `Banco de Dados` (a.k.a. List allTrainings`) deve sobreviver persistir depois de cada requisição, neste caso a lista deve ser instancia de forma estática.

Neste caso, você irá precisar realizar um lock na Lista, sempre que precisar alterar a mesma, ou seja, durante uma inserção ou remoção, isto para evitar que acessos simultâneos não causem inconsistências.

Também gostaria de apontar outros dois pontos:

1. Não vejo necessidade de mater estas duas listas de treinamentos.
2. Você não deve usar o `.List()` de forma demasiada, cada vez que você utiliza este recurso, você está criando uma nova lista, que por sua vez está ocupando memoria de forma desnecessária.

por fim, se precisar realizar um pre-carregamento da sua lista, então crie um método estático para criar a lista.

**Repository**

```
public class TrainingRepository : ITrainingRepository
{
    private static List<Treinamento> allTrainings = initTrainings();

    private static List<Treinamento> initTrainings()
    {
        var training = new Treinamento() { 
            ID = 1, 
            Name = "João da Silva", 
            Duration = "45min", 
            StartDate = DateTime.Parse("10/10/2015"), 
            EndDate = DateTime.Parse("31/10/2015"), 
            Instructor = "Paula", Time = "4:00PM" 
        };
        var listOfTrainings = new List<Treinamento>();
        listOfTrainings.Add(training);
        return listOfTrainings;
    }

    public TrainingRepository()
    {

    }

    public IEnumerable<Treinamento> GetTrainings()
    {
        return TrainingRepository.allTrainings;
    }

    public Treinamento GetTrainingByID(int id)
    {
        return TrainingRepository.allTrainings.Find(t => t.ID == id);
    }

    public void InsertTraining(Treinamento training)
    {
        lock(TrainingRepository.allTrainings)
        {
            training.ID = (
                from b in TrainingRepository.allTrainings 
                orderby b.ID descending 
                select b.ID
            ).DefaultIfEmpty(0).First() + 1;        
            TrainingRepository.allTrainings.Add(training);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetInstructor()
    {
        return (from key in trainingData select key.Instructor).Distinct();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    TrainingRepository _trainingRepository = new TrainingRepository();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Treinamento> allTrainings = _trainingRepository.GetTrainings();
        return View(allTrainings);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreatePartialView()
    {
        return PartialView("CreatePartialView");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Create(Treinamento training)
    {
        _trainingRepository.InsertTraining(training);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetInstructorList()
    {
        var allInstructors = _trainingRepository.GetInstructor();
        return Json(allInstructors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Toby, deu certo. Obrigada! Só não entendi o termo que você citou UnitOfWork. O que significa?

Comment: Não sei lhe explicar direito, mas basicamente seria um objeto que irá coordenar uma transação envolvendo múltiplos repositórios.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda Toby!